# Fan is loud but CPU and temperature is low

Tags: 13.10, fan

This is a problem that I had a while ago (1 year ago), but I decided to ask about it now.

So, my laptop's (Satellite L-655) fan is too loud, but the CPU usage is low and the temperature is low as well (44 Celcious, from Jupiter).

This problem does not apply only to Ubuntu, but on Windows 7 as well, so I don't think it's Ubuntu's fault.

In the summer, I took my laptop for cleanup because of the loud fan and the high temperatures it had at that time - they opened it and removed the dust. The high temperatures were fixed, but not the fan.

Could this a problem with the hardware? What could be the cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no overheating, then you might want to clear all the dust out of your machine, because if the fan is really dusty, it can get somewhat noisy too.

You'll also want to try lubricating your fans.  This should help get your fan running faster and quieter.  If all else fails, you may need to replace the fan entirely.

Comment: I have already taken the laptop to a pc shop to remove its dust.

Comment: Then you might want to try to either lubrication, and/or replacement.